# ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS : cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

I'm calling  ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS via Intent.its is showing cannot be resolved or is not a field caused while importing Project from outside. What should i do now ?

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Comment: Did u import `import android.provider.Settings;` into your Activity?

Comment: I tried this, it is not Importing- import android.provider.Settings;

Comment: Why? becz it's working in my case.

Comment: Are you importing this into your Activity?

Comment: Actually its working code in my old eclipse since 6 months back. Same Project everything is fine but not Importing In my New Eclipse But Eclipse was working with other projects.

Comment: ok then update your Android Tools and Platform. Eclipse might to not find this Resources properly.

Comment: hey @M D its working i tried like this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48337/discussion-between-m-d-and-crishnan)

Comment: used Intent viewIntent=new Intent();
   viewIntent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
      startActivity(viewIntent);

Comment: then Conclusion is Older Android set `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` and Newer Andoid set `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTING‌​S`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this..

I guess your import is wrong

Use

```
import android.provider.Settings;
```

Or try like below.

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Comment: I tried this way But Settings are not Importing even i copied import android.provider.Settings; Showing like remove import error

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
startActivity(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
```

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse check properties of your project, select 'Android' and check target name is 'Android 6.0' or +