# Android. How can I jump to a system's activity with a '$' symbol in its path?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

In my application,I want to jump to the system's location setting page. By running

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep "mFocusedActivity"
```

I get the activity path:

```
mFocusedActivity: ActivityRecord{eaaabab u0 com.android.settings/.Settings$LocationSettingsActivity t230}
```

And then I tried to jump to this page with the code.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings.LocationSettingsActivity")
startActivity(intent)
```

But the Application throws an `ActivityNotFoundException`.
**How can I jump to the activity ?**
I noticed a special symbol **'$'** in this Activity，What does this **$** symbol mean ?

#### Solutions

As the @DavidWasser answers.

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings\$LocationSettingsActivity")
```

In this way, I succeed to jump to this Activity. Originally this Activity is window mode in the system settings page, now I jump directly to this page is full screen. But its functions are working properly.

> In summary, we can jump to an internal class in this way, Thank you to everyone who answered.

Comment: `$` means inner class.So you can't directly jump to that class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACTION\_LOCATION\_SOURCE\_SETTINGS : cannot be resolved or is not a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004989/action-location-source-settings-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Comment: @VivekMishra Why not if you have the parent class instance?

Comment: Did you try `intent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$LocationSettingsActivity")`?

Comment: @m0skit0 When launching an `Activity`, you just provide the package and class name to the Android framework. The framework then needs to instantiate the class. The framework isn't smart enough to instantiate the outer class and then the inner class, so in this case you don't have the parent class instance.

Comment: @VivekMishra actually it must be possible to directly jump to that class because the class is an `Activity` and the Android framework needs to be able to instantiate all `Activity` instances itself. Even though this is an inner class, because it is an `Activity` it **must b** declared `static`, meaning that it can stand on its own and does not need an instance of the outer class to exist.

Comment: @VivekMishra However $ can indicate a static inner class which can be instantiated without the parent class.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thank you ,It worked.                              ````intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings\$LocationSettingsActivity")
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the class name including the "$". This indicates the `LocationSettingsActivity` is an inner class:

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$LocationSettingsActivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in opening the location settings, you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);

ActivityInfo activityInfo = intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0);
if (activityInfo != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```